# Android/Java - Margin on left/right/bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, button, margin

how i can remove these margins from my buttons?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBPhR.png

I want to have 100% width buttons :/

my activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#1379ff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:backgroundTint="#313131" />

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: post your code ?

Comment: in your layout you might have default margins specified remove them

Comment: Can you please post your xml also

Comment: i have added my xml into post

Comment: Is your code complete?

Comment: The gap in your image looks like "padding". Try to set a negative number to "android:padding" to remove this, like "-6dp"

Comment: This question can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989961/how-to-remove-extra-padding-or-margin-in-material-design-button

Comment: @sakiM when i do that, it removes only "gap" on left, on right its stronger

Answer (score 0):

```
Use negative margin to the parent layout like below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"

 >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#1379ff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:backgroundTint="#313131" />
```

Answer (score -1):

in your `RelativeLayout` you should use `fill_parent`
and maybe it is because of it's **Parent Width**